# Problem Forwarding Port 22 for SSH

Tags: wan, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward port 22 so I can SSH into my PC from a different network but it doesn't seem to be working. I can do `ssh mihkel@my_public_ip` from the network that the PC is on but it doesn't work on any other network. I've made sure port 22 is allowed in the Windows Firewall and that the IP is correct.. Here is my port forwarding config:[image]

I have a Inteno DG400 router and the PC is connected on LAN via Ethernet.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask htis question on [su].

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't assign "source port" because when you trying connecting from PC1 to PC2 using ssh only destination port is 22. Source port that PC1 using is dynamically assigned and it could be anything.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change it when I'm home and report back.

Comment: If I leave "source-port" empty I get an error saying it cannot be empty, I've tried to set it to 0 but this is not accepted either.

Comment: then the only thing you can do you need to find a software where you can set also source port